# How to return "int array" from native method to java in NDK

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

see i have native function in nativeLib

```
 public native int [] getArrayNative();
```

which i am using like this

```
 private static int[] DEMO_NODES;

 DEMO_NODES =  nativeLib.getArrayNative();
```

in c code it has

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_testing_NativeLib_getArrayNative
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    int array[] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2 };
    jintArray temp = (*env)->NewIntArray(env,20);
    temp[0] = array[0];   // gives error
    return temp;    
}
```

here i want to return whole arry[] but i can not understand how to do that. 
here i have taken new array temp inside that tried to copy value of arry[] but it shows error. so how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SetIntArrayRegion`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#27761) to fill the array, `jintArray` ist just some magic
internal structure, nothing you can access using indices.

> **Prototype** void SetArrayRegion(JNIEnv *env,  array,
>   jsize start, jsize len,  *buf);